# Foreach if and else problems PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having a few problems with php when I use a `foreach()` for 10 arrays and use the `if(variable = something){}else{}` to show what i want from it.

The else returns everything 10x.

What I need help with is when 6111 or 6112 does not exists it shows only once what i have in the `else{}` instead of showing it 10x since there is 10 arrays.

```
foreach(){
    if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6111){
         //dothis
    } else if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6112){
         //dothis
    } else {
        //dothis
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

I also tried doing this, with the `if{} else {}` out side the foreach but it instead of returning everything multiple time it mixes them all up in each other.

```
foreach(){
    if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6111){
        $statplayemasteriesslotsID1 = 6111;
    } else if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6112){
        $statplayemasteriesslotsID1 = 6112;
    } 
}


if($statplayemasteriesslotsID1 == 6111){
    //dothis
} else if($statplayemasteriesslotsID1 == 6112){
   //dothis
} else {
   //dothis
}
```

I currently am using the last way i done it if anyone knows away to stop this please let me know. thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more code with us. What is the condition inside `foreach(){`? What is the relation between `foreach(){` and `$statplayemasteriesslotsID`. From what you have right now as your question, it seems that in all the loops none of the conditions in the `if` and `else if` are true, and that's why the `else` condition happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
$doC = false;

foreach(){
    if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6111){
        //dothis
    } else if($statplayemasteriesslotsID == 6112){
        //dothis
    } else {
       //don't do it yet, just set a flag:
       $doC = true;
    }
}

if($doC) {
    // do it once only!
}
```

Comment: I done like this and returns nothing when its should return the else

Comment: I found part of the problem. So its resolved past of my problem, but it still shows for the if inside the foreach() multiple times 
http://jsfiddle.net/0bs5mu6e/14/  
Shows like this: https://gyazo.com/56f2cdb1deaacaebf88f29b98bfb15ed 
Instead of like this: https://gyazo.com/a9d96effbf07504ee50f42e462861426

Comment: When i remove the $doCtest123 = true; and put $doCtest123 = false; It works for everything else but what i want the else to show wont show

Comment: Since its checking all 10 arrays in the foreach when it finds nothing it does the else but when it find something it does the if and the else as the other arrays having nothing. How would i get around that? Thanks in advance